# How to reload the css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Probably the answer to my question is simple, but I have not found the answer.
I would like to know whether I can call a "className".css file in a mouseover(mouseout) function. For example:

```
<div id="thing" class="classes" onmouseover="????call the .css file???">My Name</div>
```

I dont want to write: `onmouseover = "style.color:'blue'"` ...

Let me explain why I want this. Lets say I have a NAME.css file. This css will make the word "My name" turn into red color.

I have this html
///

```
<div id="thing" class="classes" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'">My Name</div><br>
```

///

I thought that once the mouse is out, the word "My Name" will be red again(this because of the css file), but it is not. Is it possible to write something like this?:

My Name

I dont want to write this:

```
<div id="thing" class="classes" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'" onmouseout = "this.style.color='red'">My Name</div>
```

Hope it is clear and understandable. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Joel

Comment: Just use the :hover pseudo selector.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `:hover` pseudo class instead in CSS.

```
.classes:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a css property in css

```
div#thing{
    color: red;
}
div#thing:hover{
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is possible, use the `:hover` pseudoselector:

```
#thing { color: red; }
#thing:hover { color: blue; }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/TE58U/)